# Opening folder with no law to escape

Tags: c#

how open a folder from winforms in this way that user couldn't move from this folder to another?

He could only remove or add files to this folder.

And he could close this folder and return to his winforms app.

Comment: Are you talking about the standard OpenFileDialog?

Comment: yes, but without icons to address changing (listbox with folders, icons of desktop, mycomputer etc)

Comment: Better to create your own Winform with listing of files from that particular folder.This way you can even customize it in case there is still more feature changes.

Comment: yes, but what with icons of files(it's important for user which will be exploring for particular photo)

Comment: i mean thumbnails of files, not icons

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible (I assume you mean open it in Explorer). Your best bet is to have him run as a user that only has permissions to open that folder. What I mean is that you should try and solve this using the inbuilt Windows ACL system.

Perhaps if you provide more details we can help solve the underlying issue.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that:

http://www.ssware.com/fileview/fileview.htm

I wanna show windows explorer without Address bar

Comment: Ah, well it seems that he has just re-implemented the interface inside his DLL. He isn't magically calling the Explorer interface somehow (as far as I would guess, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
    path = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;


ImageList imageList1 = new ImageList();
imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(256, 256);
imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth24Bit;
string[] iconFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");

foreach (string iconFile in iconFiles)
{
   try
   {
      imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(iconFile));
   }
   catch
   {
         MessageBox("Error","");
   }
}

this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
this.listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;

for (int j = 0; j < imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

    item.ImageIndex = j;   
    this.listView1.Items.Add(item);               
}
```

This displays thumbnails of files. How to stick this with files? Deleting, renaming??